# How to install R 4.0.* on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)?

Tags: debian, upgrade, raspbian, r

I believe I have followed the instructions on the relevant [CRAN site](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian/#installation) to update R to the newest version (currently R 4.0.5) but with no luck.

I'm running

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

with R version

```
$ R --version
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"
```

What I did is, *first* add repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/
```

which currently looks like this:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/
```

*Second*, to fetch and import the current signing key:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
```

*Third*,

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Now I attempted to install, but that fails.

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.5-1~bustercran.0) but 3.5.2-1 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.5-1~bustercran.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.5-1~bustercran.0) but 3.5.2-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

To solve the issue I tried several things like fixing dependencies issue,

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

re-installing `r-base-core`,

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt remove r-base-core
$ sudo apt install r-base-core
```

and using the [command](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian/#supported-branches) at the CRAN site mentioned above.

```
$ sudo apt install -t buster-cran40 r-base
```

But I still have R version 3.5.2, i.e. I always get R 3.5.2 instead of R 4.0.5.

How do I get R 4.0.5 onto my Raspberry pi?

---

#### Edit

*More infos:*

```
$ apt search r-base-core
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
pandoc/stable 2.2.1-3+b2 armhf
  general markup converter

r-base/buster-cran40 4.0.5-1~bustercran.0 all
  GNU R statistical computation and graphics system

r-base-core/stable,now 3.5.2-1 armhf [installed]
  GNU R core of statistical computation and graphics system

r-base-core-dbg/stable 3.5.2-1 armhf
  GNU R debug symbols for statistical comp. language and environment

r-cran-date/stable 1.2.38-1+b1 armhf
  GNU R package for date handling
```

Comment: Remove `r-base-core` and then `apt-get install r-base-core=4.0.5`.

Comment: @NasirRiley Thanks, getting `E: Version '4.0.5' for 'r-base-core' was not found`, though.

Comment: Try `apt-get install r-base-core=4.0.5-1`.

Comment: @NasirRiley Nope, just `E: Version '4.0.5-1' for 'r-base-core' was not found`

Comment: @jay.sf did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade buster to bullseye. r-base-core >4 is available. I successfully installed it